# Making a phone call from iPhone application

Tags: nsurl, iphone

I am getting a little tricked up right now so I need some help.  I have an iPhone app and within the app I want to be able to call a number. (Hopefully this is possible?)

I have looked at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

and I am a little confused.  It has an  with the tel:XXXXXXXX but in objective c and the iPhone sdk can you have just a plain  link??

Right now I am trying to use something along the lines of the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:#######"]];
```

(the ##### is a my second phone number hardcoded in for testing purposes)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you have should work, but NOT in the simulator

Comment: so that means I can't test phone calling feature on simulator? or is there any other way to make a call, which works on simulator as well?

Comment: I have run it from xcode using my iPhone and have a button that when clicked has a function that this code in it and it still wont do anything.  Thats why I am confused.

Comment: Same for SMS messaging. The hardware is not there and the simulator just won't work, or will crash in weird ways. You have to check if the capacity is available, otherwise it will crash on iPod touches, iPads or iPhones without sim cards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking specifically. The code you have there should launch their dialer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that will work on a physical phone but it won't work in the simulator....  I don't understand what your question/problem is.